# Send two inputs to stdin from child_process.spawn()

Tags: node.js

Given I have a `name.js` script which has two prompts as follows:

```
What is your first name? Foo 
What is your surname? Bar
Hello Foo Bar.
```

How would I be able to use `child_process.spawn()` to send **two inputs** such that the script correctly prints the first and surname?

I have tried using `[process].write(Foo); [process].end();`, however this results in the stream being closed, unable to accept the surname.

---

The following is the code for `name.js`. It uses the [prompts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompts) npm package.

```
const prompts = require('prompts');

prompts({
  type: 'text',
  name: 'firstName',
  message: 'What is your first name?',
})
  .then(response => {
    prompts({
      type: 'text',
      name: 'surname',
      message: 'What is your surname?',
    })
    .then(secondResponse => {
      console.log(`Hello ${response.firstName} ${secondResponse.surname}.`);
    });
  });
```

---

The following is a few things I have tried to get this to work, but to no avail.

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process');

const sampleOne = spawn('name.js');
sampleOne.stdin.write('Foo\nBar');
sampleOne.stdin.end(); // This method results in 'First name' being 'FooBar'.

const sampleTwo = spawn('name.js');
sampleTwo.stdin.write('Foo');
sampleTwo.stdin.end();
sampleTwo.stdin.write('Bar');
sampleTwo.stdin.end(); // Correctly writes 'Foo' as 'First name' but cannot write 'surname' as stdin steam is closed.
```

Comment: Is your child process, a node js script?

Comment: In this example yes, but ideally the solution would work for any command line process.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I've added a code sample, but I'm not sure it's entirely relevant to the answer.

Comment: Can you add the parent process code?

Comment: I have added parent process code sample.

Comment: You should not close `stdin`

Comment: It should be a continuous stream

Answer (score 1):

You should not `close` the standard input stream to the child process if you want to continue sending data to the process. It should be a continuous stream. In case if you are wondering how to send more than one input to the process you may have to use a input separator like `sampleOne.stdin.write('Foo\nBar\n');` that you implemented in your first scenario and handle it on the child script.

Think about a user following this process manually, `What is your first name?` is displayed to the console (So written to the `stdout` on the process). User type `Foo` and then enter (`\n`). So the input will be `Foo\n` and the stdin stream doesn't close the stdin. Then `What is your surname?` printed into the terminal, Then user inputs `Bar` and then press Enter(`\n`), so the input will be `Bar\n`

So the total stream inputs are `Foo\nBar\n`, if this does not work try waiting till the second output printed into the console then send `Bar\n`.

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that as the first sample shows. Am I using the wrong separator? This was tested on Windows.